# Which one is the correct atlassian-sdk version?

Tags: atlassian-plugin-sdk

I installed Atlassina-SDK and execute "atlas-verions" command, then command line prompt following message:

```
$ atlas-version

ATLAS Version:    6.2.4
ATLAS Home:       /Applications/Atlassian/atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.2.2
ATLAS Scripts:    /Applications/Atlassian/atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.2.2/bin
ATLAS Maven Home: /Applications/Atlassian/atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.2.2/apache-maven-3.2.1
AMPS Version:     6.2.3
--------
Executing: /Applications/Atlassian/atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.2.2/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin/mvn --version -gs /Applications/Atlassian/atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.2.2/apache-maven-3.2.1/conf/settings.xml
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
   Colorizing console...
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-15T01:37:52+08:00)
Maven home: /Applications/Atlassian/atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.2.2/apache-maven-3.2.1
Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

I found there are 3 versions, **6.2.2**, **6.2.3** and **6.2.4** in the above message.
Can somebody tell me which one number the atlassina-sdk version is? And what do the other 2 version numbers mean? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you missed one, the 3.2.1.  But they are different products so as long as they are compatible then you should be good to go.   That looks just fine and may be the latest and greats of the best on the planet.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this at one point I believe the 6.2.4 was out of synch.  It appears to have been resolved if you reinstall the Atlassian SDK.